# Meaning of "be getting "

Tags: american-english

I see this expression a lot these days and I have searched about it and didn't find an answer.

Some examples:

- We are getting prepared
- We are getting married
- We are getting better

Answer (score 0):

They do not all have precisely the same meaning.

> We are getting prepared

We are doing something now and as a result at some future time we will be ready.

> We are getting married

We are planning to do this at some future time

> We are getting better

Several possibilities: We are still ill but we are not as ill as we were and so we hope at some future time we will feel better. We are currently not very good at the task but we are practicing and we are better at it than we once were.

Comment: What is the type of "prepared", i mean is it a adjective and can you give examples about using it

Comment: And what if i said "we are getting planned" ? Is it mean that we are now planning

Comment: _We are getting planned_ sounds really awkward to me. _We are making plans_ is what I would normally say. I have no idea what part of speech _prepared_ is, I only speak the language I have never studied its grammar.

Comment: It seems to me "prepared" is a state of being, you can be prepared, not prepared, even partially prepared, but it is a state of being that has this name. "Planned" is not such a state, no one speaks of "being planned". So you cannot say "we are getting planned", because that is not a state that you can talk about  moving towards, whereas "getting prepared" does talk about moving towards a state.

Answer (score 0):

The basic meaning of *get* in all these examples is *become*, or *change state into*.

> We are getting prepared -> We are taking action to become prepared

> We are getting married -> We are (arranging to) change ourselves into the state of being married.

> We are getting better -> We are doing something to become better than we are.